# how to add a touch sound(on/off) preference in settings activity

Tags: java, android, settings

how can i add toggle button for touch sound preference for whole app on settings.. 
 **similar like this image**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Save the status of the sound(on/off) in the preference of your application.
In the onclick listener get the status of the sound from preference as follows.

```
 PreferenceManager preferenceManager = new PreferenceManager(this);
 preferences.edit()
            .putBoolean("status", true/false)
            .apply();
```

get the status from the preference and update onclick listener

```
 boolean sound_status = preferences.getBoolean("status", false)
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(sound_status == true){
               //play sound
            }

            // do your work
        }
    });
```

do this for all of your click listener